# Im trying to build a portfolio website in reatctjs and I can't figure out how to fix these problems,

Tags: reactjs

not sure how to fix these errors I have done all the steps in this guide

https://medium.com/technoetics/create-a-developer-portfolio-using-reactjs-d34ea1bfb18e

[image]

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d453C.png       this a screenshot of the problem

Comment: Hi @Ryan, Welcome to stackoverflow. Please elaborate your question like what problem you are facing. What have you tried so far and seems like broken to you. Please post somecode so community can help you.

Comment: Why are you creating a component inside a render function? I don't think its correct. You have to create the component outside the render function or any other component. Create component in seperate js file and import it where you want to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

maybe you just have to delete this:

```
var NewComponent = React.createClass({render:function() { return (
```

as you already have a return statement beforehand.

---

its pretty hard to understand the real problem with the provided information here, but I try to help.

You should maybe think about writing just a functional component like:

```
function NewComponent() {
    return (
        <>
            <header>...</header>
            ...otherstuff...
        </>
    )
}
```

Please mind that this component declaration can not live inside of another render function, so you have to create it beforehand and render it like this:

```
function OtherComponent() {
    return (
        <NewComponent />
    )
}
```

Hope this helps pointing in the right direction!